# Why would an object implementing a trait expect a longer lifetime than a concrete object?

Tags: rust

I've been playing around with rust as a hobby for a few years now. Just when I thought I was starting to understand lifetimes, I found this. I was trying to "genericize" a function to handle different types of data. The following is an MRE of my problem.

```rust
pub struct BorrowedData<'data> {
    inner: Vec<&'data u16>
}

struct ConcreteData {
    data: Vec<u16>
}

impl TryFrom<BorrowedData<'_>> for ConcreteData {
    type Error = ();

    fn try_from(value: BorrowedData<'_>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        Ok(Self {
            data: value.inner.into_iter().map(|n| *n).collect()
        })
    }
}


pub fn test_generic<'data,Entity: TryFrom<BorrowedData<'data>,Error=()>>() -> Result<(),()> {

    let data = [4,8,15,16,23,42];

    let borrowed = BorrowedData {
        inner: data.iter().collect()
    };

    let _data = Entity::try_from(borrowed)?;

    // ...Process and save data to file in appropriate structure

    Ok(())

} // data dropped here while still borrowed?

pub fn test_concrete() -> Result<(),()> {

    let data = [4,8,15,16,23,42];

    let borrowed = BorrowedData {
        inner: data.iter().collect()
    };

    let _data = ConcreteData::try_from(borrowed)?;

    // ...Process and save data to file in appropriate structure

    Ok(())

}
```

Which returns a compilation error:

```
error[E0597]: `data` does not live long enough
  --> src/mre.rs:26:16
   |
21 | pub fn test_generic<'data,Entity: TryFrom<BorrowedData<'data>,Error=()>>() -> Result<(),()> {
   |                     ----- lifetime `'data` defined here
...
26 |         inner: data.iter().collect()
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
29 |     let _data = Entity::try_from(borrowed)?;
   |                 -------------------------- argument requires that `data` is borrowed for `'data`
...
35 | } // data dropped here while still borrowed?
   | - `data` dropped here while still borrowed
```

It works fine in the concrete function, but the generic function causes a problem.

Can anyone explain this?

And is there a way to fix the `test_generic` function?* Or is this impossible?

* Without touching the `data` variable or the `BorrowedData` struct. The latter is a mock for an object returned from an external c library call, and the former is where it is because it was the only way I could reproduce the error. And it's the error that I'm getting in my real code.

Comment: Nitpick: Why `TryFrom` and not just `From`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It wasn't necessary for this example, but the conversions in my original code could fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This signature:

```
pub fn test_generic<'data, Entity: TryFrom<BorrowedData<'data>, Error = ()>>() -> Result<(), ()>
```

Uses a caller-provided lifetime for `'data`, which is always going to be larger than the body of the function.  Because you call `Entity::try_from(borrowed)` the compiler infers that `borrowed` must be valid for `'data` which is impossible because it borrows from `data` which *cannot* outlive the body of the function, and so you get the compilation error.

You need a higher-ranked trait bound (HRTB) which allows you to say things like "`Entity` must implement `TryFrom<BorrowedData<'a> ...>` for *any* valid lifetime `'a`," which can then be shorter than the body of the function.

```
pub fn test_generic<Entity: for<'a> TryFrom<BorrowedData<'a>, Error = ()>>() -> Result<(), ()>
```

This change allows your code to compile.

Comment: Another way to think about this: the caller may choose `'data` to be `'static`, but `data` is obviously not `'static`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This had been giving me a huge headache trying to figure this out.